# Showing 3D globe view using flutter_map + Mapbox studio

Tags: flutter, mapbox, fluttermap

I'm using flutter_map plugin with a MapBox style and I'm trying to display a 3D globe view in app

[image: Globe]

This is my current FlutterMap

```
FlutterMap(
                  mapController: controller,
                  options: MapOptions(
                    maxZoom: 19,
                    zoom: latestZoom,
                    center: userLocation ?? LatLng(lat, lon),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TileLayer(
                      urlTemplate:   "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{username}/{mapStyleId}/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={accessToken}",
                      additionalOptions: const {
                        'username': <username>,
                        'mapStyleId': <style.id>,
                        'accessToken': <access.token>,
                      },
                      maxZoom: 19,
                    ),

                      MarkerLayer(
                        markers: [
                          <markers>
                        ],
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
```

After some research I found out that the part responsible for the map view is the "crs" property in MapOptions and that the right projection and transform can give me the target result.

How can I find/create the right Crs class with the globe projection to be able to show a 3D globe view while maintaining the ability to display markers on it?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
Had to write it natively, exposing a whole other set of challenges in the process.

Comment: Any update on showing custom marker for 3d earth for flutter?

Answer (score 0):

there is one more package `flutter_earth` using Tiles. in the 3D view, the only issue is that `flutter_earth` doesn't support a custom marker.

here is Link

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_earth/versions

[image]

Comment: Any update on showing custom marker for 3d earth for flutter?